# Type inheritance with TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to create multiple types in an app, each of which should follow a certain structure. The generic structure is called COMPONENT. Two specific components are HEADING and TEXT. I want them to be a subtype of COMPONENT, so in this case, I would want typescript to warn me that the type "hero" is not of ELEMENT_TYPE.

I'm setting these types up in a type declaration file called `types.d.ts`.

How do I indicate that HEADING and TEXT should conform the COMPONENT type?

```js
declare type ELEMENT_TYPE = "div" | "p" | "h1" | "button";

declare type COMPONENT = {
  type: ELEMENT_TYPE;
  children: string;
  styles: any;
};

declare type HEADING = {
  type: "hero";
  children: string;
  styles: any;
} 

declare type TEXT = {
  type: "p";
  children: string;
  styles: any;
}
```

I'm looking to do something like:

```js
declare type HERO: COMPONENT = {
  type: "hero";
  children: (COMPONENT | string)[];
  styles: CSSProperties;
}
```

Comment: What's `CSSProperties`?  Can you make this a [mre] with no external dependencies?

Comment: @jcalz pretty sure it's a [core type from React](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5ea594dd5691913cb7bf11444aa56c4517599b96/types/styled-components/index.d.ts#L15), which makes this whole question kinda suspect...

Comment: @jcalz irrelevant

Comment: @Vivick It's relevant to my IDE, which is how I like to answer questions. If you don't think it's relevant that's your prerogative, but I'm still asking for it from OP, to make this a [mre] as recommended in [ask].

Comment: @Sventies does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjlMbm) meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining (if we can just remove `CssProperties` from your question entirely). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz that approach is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @jcalz as Jared Smith mentions, it's a react type but its not relevant for the question, so I edited it out.

Comment: @JaredSmith why would a question be "suspect" if I use a React core type in it? Anyway the usage was irrelevant so as I mentioned I edited it out

Comment: @Sventies just to be clear, I said suspect not bad/wrong. As to why: you seem to be creating a system of types and components that runs parallel to? on top of? React, and the question will always be "why?". What value does it add that justifies the increase in complexity vs just modeling it (however awkward it might be at times) in React itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you're looking for a type-level version of [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator), which would just check if your `HERO` type satisfies `COMPONENT` without widening it.  We can write a utility type that behaves like that:

```
type Satisfies<T, U extends T> = U;
```

So `Satisfies<T, U>` is always equivalent to `U`, but you will get a compiler error unless `U` satisfies `T`.  Let's test it out:

```
declare type HERO = Satisfies<COMPONENT, {
  type: "hero";
  children: (COMPONENT | string)[];
  styles: any;
}>; // error,  Type '"hero"' is not assignable to type 'ELEMENT_TYPE'
```

Looks good. You get the desired error. It would be nicer if the error only showed up on the `type` property, but we don't have a lot of control over this. Hopefully it's good enough for you to proceed.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAFwJ4AckFEAyWCyWAcgCoD6JAmgApaIC8iARCAJYBuTiAPs+l7yYALAIwDmAIwCuyZAHsAdkwDcwUJFgIUGJAGEA8vmr6ixEg0QBvYIm2YAXIlwEzFGllW2IQ1lBAIFRwBnZDhWBQBzT0QQ1CgwIMcYBVRVAF9VdWh4JDRMRAAJLABBABEASSIAcQtrWzywR2EwODkVG0RvX38wQJjQ8KiO2PjExGTU4DS1cGytBsQSLAANc0Y6u0a+dq8fPwDggcjokYSklPS1BYBlGGRWIIAzVgSAHhIAGkQAVUQwAA9kL0QEFFgA+CzfTKzTS5HSFLAAJX0Flu9yeLyCrwMRhMZi+GwaTSELTa0S6+16jgAFDjjKZSDx+mFIgBKADaAF0TmhRudJmkwcpEAB6EV-OCtOBfRbwgDkzVaTDliAeiAUcmQ4yCQVYEQUMAk8RQck2iDlzkIpDctDlwCAA)

Comment: Sorry, I want to create all of this in a declaration (.d.ts) file. In there, I still don't get an error if I don't conform the HERO type to the COMPONENT type. Outside of it in a normal .ts file your answer works perfectly. Is this something that I can change in my tsconfig? Or has it to do with the nature of a declaration file?

Comment: I don't know. Given that this answers the question as asked, and you confirmed in the comments that it met your needs, I do hope you'll accept this and then open up a new question if you have further issues.  My intent when I ask things like "does this approach meet your needs? If so I will write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?" is to avoid this sort of thing where I spend time and effort writing up an answer that doesn't solve the problem. The idea was that you would actually check before saying yes. How shall we proceed here?

Comment: Hmm. And I also made clear in my initial question that I'm trying to get this to work in a type declaration file. But sure, I could / should have checked before, that's true. Just not sure how to start over, but I'll give it a shot

Comment: Well, if it doesn't actually answer the question because you mentioned the .d.ts file, then I guess you shouldn't accept this, but I did assume you said it worked for you because you checked. I have no idea if I can figure out how to go from here to solve it.  It's up to you what to do, but you'll probably have a better shot at getting an answer with a new question. ‍♂️ Sorry and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for conjunction/intersection types:

```
declare type HERO = COMPONENT & {
    type: "hero";
    children: (COMPONENT | string)[];
    styles: CSSProperties;
}
```

It means that `A & B` is both an `A` and a `B`.

However in your case, this wouldn't make much sense as you'd have incompatible types for `type`

Comment: I was already familiar with this approach, it's not what I was looking for. I want something similar but then it should throw when I use "hero" instead of a valid ELEMENT_TYPE